# Async Select in react not loading options

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to load options for select field dynamically using React-Select. Here is my method that returns the loadOptions in Select.

```
 onChange(e)  {
    console.log("Value Printed : " + e);
 if(e.length > 3) {


 new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {           
    const url = `http://localhost:3010/cityNames?name=${e}`;
    fetch(url)
   .then(results => results.json())
   .then(data => {        
       var options = [];    
        options = data;
        console.log("return value from server: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        return {options: data};
   });
    }, 1000);
});

} else {console.log("Enter 3 chars");}
};
```

But my options aren't displaying.

Here is the render component.

```
   <AsyncSelect
    isClearable
    loadOptions={this.onChange}
    onInputChange={this.onChange}
   />
```

The console log shows the correct results.
My data variable is:

```
 [{"label":"Dallas","value":680780}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your component doesn't re-render when the data is fetched. Try to use state instead.

```
.then((data) => {      
    this.setState({ options: data });
});
```

And inside render:

```
<Select
   isClearable
   options={this.state.options}
   onInputChange={this.onChange}
/>
```

By the way, I really doubt that you have to use Async React Select. I think that the normal one would be enough, with a slight logic change.

Your code should look like:

```
onChange = (inputValue) => {
  if (inputValue.length > 3) {
      const url = `http://localhost:3010/cityNames?name=${inputValue}`;
        fetch(url)
          .then(results => results.json())
          .then(data => {
             this.setState({
                options: data,
             });
          });
    });
};
```

Comment: Well, it is not giving any errors in console, neither it shows the options on browser.

Comment: The console.log shows the values I am getting from the backend, but just it doesnt display

Comment: Here is the data variable again.

`[{"label":"Dallas","value":680780}]`

Comment: @ShivaNara Replace your async select with normal react select and it should be fine

Comment: But when I clear my text and enter a new text, it is not fetching the new results?

Comment: @ShivaNara I've edited my answer. You don't even need Promise. Consider adding some kind of debounce so the request is not fired with every key stroke that quickly (add some throttle, like 500ms)

Comment: Thanks Much. I got it working as expected. 
Could you tell me how to get the value of the option selected into a state variable?
I am trying but unable to fetch just the one value that is selected in the field

Comment: @ShivaNara You mean the default value? So its selected just right after its fetched?

Answer (score 2):

added a
`key` prop
`key={options.length}`
fixed my issue of not rendering options when options change later.
Feel free to use this or similar as a fix as well.

```
 <AsyncSelect
    key={options.length}
    loadOptions={options}
   />
```